Access failed from postman to the Weblogic routing on public URL
I have installed an ear in the Web-logic managed server and I want to access that ear with the public URL. But the issue is I am getting the error Unauthorized 401
What I am trying to do is hit the following URL from the postman.
xyz.myroutedurl.com:1234
Public URL -> xyz.myroutedurl.com:1234
weblogic managed server URL ->  172.xx.x.xxx:1001
Postman Screenshot
I tried this with the Postman but failed with the same error mentioned above.
Please help if you have any clue regarding this issue. What should I need to cross-check at the Web logic server?
NOTE: If I apply the username and password to the WebLogic admin console then it gets login successfully.
